# Button doesn't give right value

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I made a code that looks like this :

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def Click(val):
    print("Value: "+val)

var_str = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
#I want var_str to be expandable

var_list = []
for x in range(0,len(var_str)):
    var_list.append(x)
    var_list[x] = StringVar()
    var_list[x].set(var_str[x])
#I basically make a set of StringVar that contains strings in var_str

b = []
for x in range(0,len(var_list)): 
    Button(root, textvariable=var_list[x], command=lambda: Click(var_list[x].get())).pack()
#I make the set of StringVar into a set of button

root.mainloop()
```

I wanted to make a set of buttons that print their value based on the value they display
I used Stringvar because I wanted the value to be changeable later with a button
The problem is why am I keep getting "5" whenever I pressed other numbers? Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Change your code to `command=lambda x=x:Click(var_list[x].get())`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Thank you for helping! it worked. But can you explain it a bit on why we must put x=x: ?

Comment: [Read it](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)